# What's difference between using "sudo service mongod start" and "mongod"?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I can't understand what's difference between using

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and

```
mongod
```

In mongodb official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

said that to start mongodb just use `sudo service mongod start`, and its log stores in /var/log/mongodb. However, I try to run mongodb using `mongod` this way, log shows on terminal, and after I turn off the terminal, I can not find the log file.

It is confused.

Comment: In one instance you are calling the mongo service and in the other, you are just calling mongo binary directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` - Runs the command as `root`.
`service` - Manages the following program as a `daemon` (background process).
`mongod` - Obviously the MongoDB program in question.
`start` - A command that tells `service` what to do with the program in question.

Together, we get "I want to start `mongod` as a background process, and I want to run it as `root` so it has permission to do the things it needs to do". Running `mongod` by itself, however, runs the program in an ordinary fashion, i.e. as a foreground process. Typically you want to run it as a background process so that you're free to do other things, e.g. connecting to the database via shell access.

This is pretty simplified, but it should explain what you actually need to know at this point in time.